# Existence of a smooth map

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Given a smooth manifold $M^m$, a point $p \in M$, a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a linear map $L:T_pM \to \mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that exists a smooth map $f:M^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(p)=x$ and $df(p)=L$.

Any idea, solution or reference for this problem

Comment: Can you do this if $M=\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: No, I can't. I think that it use Whitney embbeding theorem and Tietze Theorem, but I can't do this.

Comment: No, you don't need anything fancy. This is a simple calculus question: I give you a linear map $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and ask for a smooth map $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that has this linear map as derivative at $0$.

Comment: And about $f(x)=p$? Can you give me more details?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Figure out the calculus question first, then the rest can be derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $M$ with $p \in U$ and $\varphi:U\to \mathbb R^n$ a diffeomorphism. Let $\chi:M\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth map with values in $[0,1]$, equal to $0$ outside of $U$ and to $1$ in a neighborhood of $1$.

$T_p\varphi$ is a isomorphism $T_pM\to \mathbb R^n$. Then, set :
$$\forall x \in M, f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\chi(x) L\cdot (T_p\varphi)^{-1}\cdot\varphi(x) & \text{if }x\in U\\
0 & \text{if }x\notin U
\end{array}\right.$$
We compute :
$$T_pf = L\cdot (T_p\varphi)^{-1}\cdot T_p\varphi = L$$